# For google calendar, how to disable 00:00 to 8:00 from GUI?

Tags: google-calendar

For the google calendar website GUI, the default time is from 00:00 to 24:00. 
However, normally 00:00 to 8:00 is useless to both me and most people. It annoys me a lot by scrolling down each time to the time after 8:00. Is it possible to disable 00:00 to 8:00? Outlook does it by starting a default day calendar at 8:00, which is set by user. People just scrolls up to see schedules before 8:00 if necessary. It is a good idea, and I wonder can I do it at google calendar?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Calendar settings

[image: google calendar settings]

and find Labs, where you can find this extension

[image: hide morning and night extension]

and set exact time ranges to hide like I do in the following image

[image: setting up the etension]